# How To Pass Value of Select Box as Foreign Key (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I am working on a Django web app - I have a select box which holds all objects from a particular model.  The select box is created in the template, it is not a part of the form directly.  When I submit, I am able to access the value selected by the user, but when I try to use the value as part of a queryset it does not return the expected values.

models.py

```
class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TaskGroupDetail(models.Model):
    taskGroup = models.ForeignKey(TaskGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    taskType = models.ForeignKey(TaskType, null=False, blank=False)
```

views.py

```
def CreateShipmentView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        shipment_form = CreateShipmentForm(request.POST)
        if shipment_form.is_valid():
            new_shipment = shipment_form.save()
            group = request.POST.get('groups') #get the task group selected
            print(group) #this returns the expected value
            
            .....
        
            #if a task group was added, create the tasks
            groupDetails = TaskGroupDetail.objects.get(taskGroup = group) #this returns a blank queryset
            print(groupDetails) #this returns a blank queryset

            return redirect('ShipmentListView')

        ...

    else:

        shipmentForm = CreateShipmentForm()
        groups = TaskGroup.objects.all()
        context = {
            'shipmentForm': shipmentForm,
            'groups': groups,
        }
        return render(request, 'create-shipment.html', context)
```

create-shipment.html

```
<form  class="well contact-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'CreateShipmentView' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          {% for error in form.Reference_Number.errors %}
            <P class='error'>{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        <h5 class="modal-title">New Shipment</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{shipmentForm|crispy}}
        </div>
        <div>
          <select id="groups" name='groups' class="custom-select custom-select-sm input-small" style="width: 100%;"> Task Group
            {% for item in groups %}
               <option>{{item}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          <button  value="" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Referencing the code above when I `print(group)` I get the value I expect, and I can see the value matches the `taskGroup` field of the objects I am trying to return in the queryset.  I am assuming this has something to do with the way the value is passed from the select to the view (like it's not a TaskGroup object or something), but I'm not really sure what to try to fix it at this point.  Any thoughts?

Comment: how about using .filter(taskGroup__in=group) instead of get(taskGroup = group) ?

Comment: I just tried that, same thing it returns just a blank queryset.

Comment: Well can you post your "group"? I don't know exactly in what type that object is.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for...it returns whatever the ```name``` is of the TaskGroup object.  If you see the model I posted above, it returns that name field as a string. I am 99% sure that's the issue, but I don't know how to make it return an object instead of string in this case.

Comment: Well if it only return the name of the task group, then instead of get(taskGroup = group). then its get(taskGroup__name = group) to access taskGroup name attribute

Comment: ahh I see - I guess it's because of what I'm doing in the model itself which is returning it as a string.  this worked, thank you for that.  if you'd like to post that as answer I will accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Group is assigned with the name of the TaskGroup, then instead of get(taskGroup = group). then its get(taskGroup__name = group) to access taskGroup name attribute.